# How do I compile my elixir program so it can run as a scheduled task in OSX?

Tags: macos, elixir

I'm current trying to set up my program as a scheduled task in OSX. I tried setting up a plist file for launchd after compiling with the mix using escript.build.

However, OSX simply ignores running my program even though launchd says it's "Loaded".

If I try to execute the program in a terminal it runs fine. Here is what my plist file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>EnableGlobbing</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.plisterine.test</string>
    <key>LowPriorityIO</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Nice</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/Lee1/Documents/flower_power_data_dump/flower_power_data_dump</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>14</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>20</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: What happens if you try running your app with elixir <app_name>?  I mean if you can get your app to run with elixir <app_name> then that'd be the command line I'd use from launchd.

Comment: That didn't seem to work either. However, I think I found I solution that I like better. Using Automator I can schedule the program to run. The batch script  in Automator just needs the /usr/local/bin/escript "plus the directory of the program". Using automator lets me look at the calendar to see every day the program ran visually instead looking in an xml file.

Comment: I suspect that launchd doesn't have permission to access your Documents folder. Try copying the program to /usr/local/bin and link to it there in the plist config file.